Unexpected result from raycasting engine
I am attempting to create a simple raycasting engine using C# and Monogame. (I'm not worried about textures at the moment.) Following this tutorial I have created code which increments the depth of the ray (I know this is inefficient and inaccurate) until it hits a wall. I then render the wall, its size dependant on the distance between the player and where the ray hit.
The user is positioned 3 squares across and 4 squares down, facing 30° from North. The expected result is a white slanted wall rendered on a black background. The following is the result from this program:

I have a class called Canvas which I use to set pixels on a texture to render using the SpriteBatch.
Canvas.cs
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace Raycaster
{
    public class Canvas
    {
        Texture2D texture;
        Color[] pixels;

        bool changed = false;

        public Canvas(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice, int width, int height)
        {
            texture = new Texture2D(graphicsDevice, width, height);
            pixels = new Color[width * height];
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch _spriteBatch)
        {
            if (changed)
            {
                changed = false;
                texture.SetData(pixels);
            }
            
            _spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Vector2(0, 0), Color.White);
        }

        public void SetPixel(int x, int y, Color color)
        {
            int position = x + (y * texture.Width);
            
            if (position >= 0 && position < pixels.Length)
            {
                pixels[position] = color;
                changed = true;
            }
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            pixels = new Color[texture.Width * texture.Height];
        }
    }
}

The following is some variables and constants I set up in Game1.cs
const int Width = 1024;
const int Height = 700;

int[,] map = { 
    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
    { 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
    { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    { 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    { 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
};

Vector2 playerPosition = new Vector2(192, 256);
double playerRotation = 30;

const double playerFOV = 60;
const double deltaAngle = playerFOV / Width;

const int unitsPerSquare = 64;

Canvas canvas;

Here is the code I used in the Draw method, in Game1:
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

canvas.Clear();

double angle = playerRotation - (playerFOV / 2);
for (int column = 0; column < Width; column++)
{
    int depth = 0;

    bool wallFound = false;
    Vector2 wallHit = new Vector2(0, 0);

    while (!wallFound)
    {
        if (depth > 1024) break;

        double x = playerPosition.X + depth * Math.Cos(angle);
        double y = playerPosition.Y + depth * Math.Sin(angle);

        if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > Width || y > Height) break;

        for (int i = 0; i < map.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            if (wallFound) break;

            for (int j = 0; j < map.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (wallFound) break;

                int value = map[i, j];
                if (value == 0) continue;
                else if (value == 1)
                {
                    Vector2 currentPosition = new Vector2((float)x, (float)y);
                    Rectangle cubeRectangle = new Rectangle(i * unitsPerSquare, j * unitsPerSquare, unitsPerSquare, unitsPerSquare);
                    if (cubeRectangle.Contains(currentPosition))
                    {
                        wallFound = true;
                        wallHit = currentPosition;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        depth++;
    }

    if (wallFound)
    {
        float distance = Vector2.Distance(playerPosition, wallHit);
        int wallRenderHeight = (int)Math.Round(Width * (1 / (distance / unitsPerSquare)));
        int wallRenderY = (Height / 2) - (wallRenderHeight / 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < wallRenderHeight; i++) canvas.SetPixel(column, i + wallRenderY, Color.White);
    }

    angle += deltaAngle;
}

_spriteBatch.Begin();
canvas.Draw(_spriteBatch);
_spriteBatch.End();

base.Draw(gameTime);


Note that Sin and Cos require an angle in radians! radians = pi * degrees / 180

@OlivierJacot-Descombes I can't believe I missed that! Converting the degrees to radians fixed it, thank you so much! I will write an answer then.

The methods Math.Sin and Math.Cos take radians rather than degrees. I fixed the program by converting my angle in degrees to radians before using the trigonometric functions:
double angleRadians = Math.PI * angle / 180;
double x = playerPosition.X + depth * Math.Cos(angleRadians);
double y = playerPosition.Y + depth * Math.Sin(angleRadians);

